# SOAP-request No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header soapUI header

Tags: javascript, ajax, soap, soapui

Im trying to accomplish SOAP-post to get back XML data.

Problem is that "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header" and I suppose that the server needs to add the header.

So I created a MockService in SOAPui and copied the server response. But I still get the same problem. In soapUI in the response I added this https://i.stack.imgur.com/fpkFG.jpg

```
        function soap() {
        var sr = MySoapRequest;

        $.ajax({  
       url: url, 
        beforeSend: function(xhr) {
        xhr.setRequestHeader("SOAPAction", "x");
        }, 
        type: "POST",  
        dataType: "xml",  
        data: sr, 
        crossDomain: true, 
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        },
        error: function (error) {
        },
        contentType: "text/xml; charset=\"utf-8\"" 
        });
            }
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

By default, browsers cannot make POST requests via AJAX to URLs which are not in the same origin as the current page. For example, if you have open a page that sits in the URL http://foo.com, and that page tries to post some data (via AJAX) to http://bar.com, you will normally get the error you are seeing now.

If you want to make this work, you have to configure your server to accept requests via Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS). I suggest that you get some information about CORS, you can find a lot of documentation online about it. An extensive overview can be found [here](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/).

As for the actual implementation of CORS on your server, it depends on which platform you are using. If you are using PHP, have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8719276/cors-with-php-headers).